# VGA and DVI-I/D Connector

Tags: graphics-card, display, vga, dvi, video-conversion

I'm fixing up an old pc and it only has a female VGA port. My monitor has both a female VGA port and a female DVI-D port. Problem is I only have a male VGA to male DVI-I connector and a male DVI-D to male DVI-D connector. Is there any chopping off of pins or swapping of connectors between cables I can do? I also have a male DVI-I to female VGA converter if that helps.
I'm getting a new cable soon but I'm dying to start on this pc.
Thanks.

Comment: No;  Just buy yourself a VGA cable.

Answer (score 2):

You're going to need a new cable, you won't be able to modify the ones you have in order to make that work. You need either a male vga to male vga, or an adapter that goes from male vga to female dvi and then use your male dvi to male dvi cable.

By the way, a plain male to male vga cable or the adapter will cost you under $5.

Comment: Why can't I just chop off one end and solder the wires?

Comment: @DylonGallagher. Because it won't work, the pins are not aligned, your request makes no sense.